# Sort a nested list in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the given dictionary example:

a) how `param1` key nested list could be sorted (?) - only child lists, parent list should not be affected.
b) since the child lists in both `param1` and `param2` are related to each other, any sorting changes in `param1` should be reflected in `param2`.

Please note only `param1` is sorted, any changes due to the sorting should be reflected in `param2`, so for example, if first child list `param1` second index becomes first, then `param2` should have the same index element swaps.

**input:**

```
din = {'param1': [[3, 5, 1], [2, 1], [10, 9, 8, 7]], 'param2': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]}
```

**expected output:**

```
dout = {'param1': [[1, 3, 5], [1, 2], [7, 8, 9, 10]], 'param2': [[3, 1, 2], [2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]]}
```

Comment: What aspect of the code you forgot to post are you asking about?

Comment: The expected output is identical to the input. There must be a better example you can use to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have tried `sort()`, but that has not produced anything meaningful, so I rather left the code out

Comment: @MarkMeyer - sorry it was posted incorrectly first, but now updated

Comment: How exactly is param2 sorted in the expected output?

Comment: What about `param2` key values, they are not sorted.

Comment: OK question updated

Comment: I guess downvoting is easier than answering! I just hoped there would be a quicker way of doing what I am after, the data is massive and would try to avoid looping through individual elements (and compare)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a pure python argsort array which will hold the indexes of the sorted items in `param1`. Then you can use those indexes to pull out the items in the other arrays in the correct order. This assumes that all the arrays are the same shape:

```
din = {'param1': [[3, 5, 1], [2, 1], [10, 9, 8, 7]], 'param2': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]}

# this will hold the indexes corresponding to the sort 
argsort = [[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(arr), key = lambda x: x[1])] for arr in din['param1']]

# apply these indexes to each item in dictionary
for key in din:
    din[key] = [[pair[0][i] for i in pair[1]] for pair in zip(din[key], argsort)]
```

**Result**

```
{'param1': [[1, 3, 5], [1, 2], [7, 8, 9, 10]],
 'param2': [[3, 1, 2], [2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to sort all sub-lists in the values of the parent dictionary :

```
dout = {k : [sorted(i) for i in v] for k,v in din.items()}
```

**Output** :

```
{'param1': [[1, 3, 5], [1, 2], [7, 8, 9, 10]], 'param2': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]}
```

Here is the code for which the items in `'param2'` key sub-lists are re-arranged according to the position of sorted `'param1` key values :

```
dout = {}
dout['param1'] = [list(zip(*sorted(zip(i,j)))[0]) for i,j in zip(din['param1'], din['param2'])]
dout['param2'] = [list(zip(*sorted(zip(i,j)))[1]) for i,j in zip(din['param1'], din['param2'])]
```

**Output** :

```
{'param1': [[1, 3, 5], [1, 2], [7, 8, 9, 10]], 'param2': [[3, 1, 2], [2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]]}
```